# How to get the all which is not in pattern grep

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get the specific string which is not included in curly braces. I use the following pattern to match what's inside the braces:

`\{[A-z0-9]+\}`

which for this string:

`{hello}cat{world}`

matches **hello** and **world** part. What I need is the opposite, so **cat** in this particular example.
It should work for any type of string, i.e.:

```
{foo} - gives nothing
{foo}bar{aaa} - gives bar
cat - gives cat
dog{cat}fish - gives dog and fish
```

I use Python if that matters.

Comment: Maybe  `r'\b(?<!\{)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b(?!})'` will be enough?

Comment: If you `re.split(r'\{[^{}]*\}', text)` you get the text between the braced expressions.

Comment: Or, `list(filter(None,re.findall(r'\{[^{}]*}|(\w+)', text)))`. But it seems you need a more generic solution though, judging by the title, hence closing.

Comment: Why don't they work? Explain

Comment: If I put (.*?)\{.*?\} as a regexp it matches entire string {hello}cat{world}, so I used your \b(?<!\{)[A-z0-9]+\b(?!}) pattern and it correctly matches **cat**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
r'\b(?<!\{)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b(?!})'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qutk06/1). **Details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\{)` - no `{` allowed immediately on the left
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more alphanumeric ASCII chars (use `[^\W_]+` to match any Unicode alphanumeric chars)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!})` - no `{` allowed immediately on the right.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/incKUq):

```py
import re
rx = r"\b(?<!\{)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b(?!})"
text = "{hello}cat{world}"
print( re.findall(rx, text) )
# => ['cat']
```